Retrieve paths of arbitrary length, exluding sub-paths
I'm working with a graph database where I store lines and their endpoints. The endpoints are contained by the lines, and since lines can share endpoints, they form chains of arbitrary length. Here's a simplified example:
:point1 :isContainedBy :line1 .
:line1 :contains :point2 .
:point2 :isContainedBy :line2 .
:line2 :contains :point3 .
[...]
:lineM :contains :pointM+1

In my graph, there are multiple disconnected chains, and I need to retrieve all of them. However, I'm facing some difficulties with my current SPARQL query:
PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/#>

SELECT ?pointStart ?pointEnd
WHERE {
  ?pointStart (:isContainedBy|:contains)+ ?pointEnd .
}

This query does return all chains, but it has two main issues:

Redundant Sub-chains: The results include all possible sub-chains. For instance, in the example above, I get not only the chain from :point1 to :pointM+1 but also all intermediate chains like :point1 to :point2, :point1 to :point3, and so on. I only need the longest chain from the start point to the end point.
Lack of Path Information: The results only include the start and end points, without detailing the path in between.

(The stated SPARQL query works fine as expected, I'm just searching for a way to retrieve the additional results.)
Is there a straightforward way to resolve these issues, possibly with some SPARQL tricks? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

There are common tricks, but they are insufficient in general. List of links to proprietary SPARQL extensions for that task: https://t.me/LinkedDataRussia/5095 (see the penultimate paragraph).

SPARQL SELECT statements return tables of results (not lists) so your resultset should be a distinct resultset of points related to the startpoint. This should do it:
PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?pointStart ?point
WHERE {
  ?pointStart (:isContainedBy/:contains)+ ?point .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?line :contains ?pointStart }
}
ORDER BY ?pointStart ?point

